# JSON: URL(string: urlString)! not woking

Tags: ios, json, swift, completionhandler, forced-unwrapping

I have this error while trying to get JSON file.

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
> value: file /Volumes/Data/Models.swift, line 40

Line 40 in my code below:

```
static func fetchFeaturedSearch(_ completionHandler: @escaping (FeaturedSearch) -> ()) {
```

When I copy the JSON data and put it in static file location, it works like a charm.
But when trying to read the json data from the search service I have the error.

**Nevertheless the data looks exactly the same!!**

Please help me with this.

Server json file: ( causes the error )

> https://nabulsiapps.com/articles-flutter/search/?lang=en&search=god&platform=ios

Same file on static JSON file: ( Works )

> http://alhudagroup-tr.com/ios/json/searchSample.json

Here is the main code:

```
struct FeaturedSearch: Decodable {
    var TotalNo: SearchCategory? 
    var categories: [SearchCategory]?
}


struct SearchCategory: Decodable {

    let categoryName: String?
    let categoryIcon: String?
    let categoryId: Int?
    let count: Int?
    let articles: [articlesList]?

    static func fetchFeaturedSearch(_ completionHandler: @escaping (FeaturedSearch) -> ()) {
let urlString =  "https://nabulsiapps.com/articles-flutter/search/?lang=en&search=god&platform=ios"

        //print(urlString)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let featuredSearch = try decoder.decode(FeaturedSearch.self, from: data)
                //print(featuredSearch)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    completionHandler(featuredSearch)
                })
                
            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }
        }) .resume()
    }
}

struct articlesList: Decodable {
    
    let id: Int?
    let old_id: Int?
    let title: String?
    let date: String?
    let imageUrl: String?
    let has_video: Int?
}
```

Comment: I executed the code and it is working fine for me.

Comment: when using the server JSON file URL(string: urlString) is nil